# bash/ cat with ${} doesn't work as expected it to go

Tags: bash, cat, variable-expansion

**Problem.**

```
directory=mac/1.x.x/**
```

even though `mac/1.x.x/**/*.sql` is right path,

```
cat ${directory}/*.sql
```

the command above said `No such file or directory` . and I want to make that possible.

**What I tried.**

to check the path is right, I did `cat mac/1.x.x/**/*.sql`. and it worked

Does having `${}` interrupt cat command's path reading or something?

Comment: did you enabled `shopt -s globstar`

Comment: are you running script from the same directory as you do it in shell?
you can try to use full directory path starting from root
cat /home/user/${directory}/*.sql

Comment: Welcome! It would be a good idea to `echo "$directory"` to know to what it is expanding after all. And give the error code verbatim.

Comment: I would for such tests even do a `set -x` instead of  `echo`, to always see what's going on. Also, to make sure that your variable `directory` has not some hidden characters in it, which might spoil everything, I would dump its content using `xxd <<<$directory`, and not `echo $directory`.

Comment: You have a directory named literally `**`?

Comment: `above said No such file or directory` Please post the whole error message.